# What is the maximum number of characters I can store in 140 characters?

Tags: c#, sms

I want to send some data (ASCII letters and numbers) but, due to a variety of factors, I'm limited to using SMS. My question, how do I send more than the SMS maximum of 140 characters?

I control the sending and receiving ends of the process. Will encryption help me out? Are there any compression mechanisms I can use such that when uncompressed I can exceed the SMS limit?

I'm also not opposed to sending multiple SMS messages and reassembly them to form the bigger payload.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think the usually approach is to use multiple messages. There are some *string encoding* libraries [(like smaz, although binary output?)](https://github.com/antirez/smaz) that are designed to "compress" short English/Latin-alphabet language strings (not to be confused with general compression). Likewise, a [better] custom encoding might be able to reduce the data ..

Comment: What's the data that you're sending?  If it could be anything, compression can't really help.  If you know something about what the data is likely to contain then you can potentially compress it.  If you know that certain characters won't be used, that some are used much more than other, etc. then there is the potential for valuable compression.  It would need to be patterns across messages since the message isn't large enough to adapt it to the specific message being sent (unlike say file encryption where you have the space to fill the overhead with such information).

Comment: [There are reliability critiques of SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service#Unreliability) and given this, multiple messages may be a risky idea -- 100% delivery is not guaranteed nor is timely delivery.

Answer (score 1):

As you have suggested yourself, you can compress your message. How much data you can send depends on various properties of your data. The easiest way to find out is to try it.

If you can't fit your data in the 140 SMS characters, and you can't use more than one SMS messages, you can store the data on a server somewhere, and use SMS just to send an ID with which you can access the server. Or you can try using an  MMS message which has a much larger limits.

Comment: There is no *general* compression I know of that is beneficial on very short strings, including zlib2. An algorithm like [smaz](https://github.com/antirez/smaz) will generally work better on very small strings .. assuming the output is still acceptable.

Comment: These aren't very small strings, they are at least 140 characters long... Anyway, OP should try it - he might need to implement some variation (probably precalculate a dictionary for the compression).

Comment: Those are very small strings. zlib2 doesn't even start to payout until about 100 bytes (as my poor memory tells me) - and then often just "marginally better" (or has to fall back to a store). There is no need to attack my previous comment. However, trying different methods is a very good suggestion.

Comment: It all depends on the data. At these sizes, using standard and rather old huffman encoding (which is, for all practical purposes, compression) can work if the various strings are similar enough.
I'm not even sure how much information you can fit in 140 SMS characters - what's the supported character set?

Comment: Appears [to be 140 octets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service#Message_size) (of unspecified encoding?), or 7-bit and UCS-2 options